# Google Sheets scripting onEdit() + Checkbox validation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've found in my testing that if a "Checkbox" Data Validation is included in the selection when a range is "deleted" (Pressing "Del"), the *onEdit()* parameter's *range* attribute will only include the cells with the checkboxes.

I thought that may be the function onEdit is actually called twice (one extra for the validation deletion), but in my testing at least, this is not the case. It also works properly with other types of Data Validation (ie ListFromARange)

Is this known ? Can it be reproduced ? Where should I report it if it is indeed an issue ?

Spreadsheet to copy and reproduce : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11X9JrD70j2pMdb8219gbkx_1nvokSweQSFZvNvRk8Rw/edit?usp=sharing

And this function which must be uncommented in the copy to reproduce:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(e.range.getRow(),4).setValue(e.range.getA1Notation());
}
```

Comment: I think that this might be a bug. About this, you can report this issue to the issue tracker. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support As a current workaround for retrieving the modified values and ranges, how about this? 1. Create a temporal Spreadsheet. 2. When the current Spreadsheet is edited, the values of current Spreadsheet are compared with the values of the temporal Spreadsheet. Here, the differences can be retrieved. 3. Copy the current values to the temporal Spreadsheet. If this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

As Tanaike has mentioned in his comment, this appears to be unintended behaviour from Apps Script's side. Regardless of the data validation, the documentation doesn't mention that this kind of behaviour should occur if the range of deleted cells contains checkboxes. As a result, I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker:

- [Deleting a range of cells from a sheet passes only the range of Checkboxes in the deleted range to the onEdit(e) event object](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148918656)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on this page as it lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Make your selection and change to the left of column 10.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  for(var i=0;i<e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1;i++) { 
    for(var j=0;j<e.range.columnEnd-e.range.columnStart+1;j++) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart+i,10).setValue(e.range.getA1Notation());
    }
  } 
}
```

This is an interesting one to play with.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  for(var i=0;i<e.range.rowEnd-e.range.rowStart+1;i++) { 
    for(var j=0;j<e.range.columnEnd-e.range.columnStart+1;j++) {
      sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart+i,e.range.columnStart+j).setValue(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart+i,e.range.columnStart+j).getA1Notation());
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm getting the same result ?

Comment: What I found is that only happens when the checkbox is in a range where there isn't anything else and that makes send because nothing else is changing.

Comment: Hmmm.. For me it happens even if there is something else in the range, as in the example sheet, where "s" fills C3.

Comment: Yeh.  I played with it some more and your right I'm getting just the range of the checkboxes.

Comment: I made my selection which contain a validation range for a column of checkboxes but instead of deleting I removed validations for that range and the range became the entire deletion range.

Comment: Very interesting

Comment: Yes, the prob is defintely related to checkbox validation. Back to old True/False dropdown ;) Thanks for your help!

Comment: One of the problems with deleting checkboxes that way is that your still left with validations in that range.  I didn't check but try taking a look at executions after doing that to see if there is any info there.

Comment: No extra info.. For me "Del" on a "Checkbox Validation" cell deletes the validation.. I don't know what you mean ?

Comment: Really not sure... Maybe just the fact that you can reproduce is something.. If you delete it, perhaps add a comment in the q ?

Comment: Well, I'll just leave it and hope that @Tanaike will come by and explain it for us.